# How can I force my fragment to redraw the layout?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, actionbarsherlock, orientation

I am using fragments in combination with tabs to display some content. One of those fragments displays data that gets updated with an async task. Since I want to keep the content that was generated on configuration change, I set `android:configChanges="orientation"` in my manifest file.

This works just fine for the fragment.However, now I have got another problem: One of my other fragments uses a custom landscape layout. This landscape layout is not set on configuration change. I guess it is because I defined in my manifest to handle the configuration change.

Now, how can I force my fragment that uses the custom landscape layout to use the landscape layout on configuration change? What do I have to put in my `onConfigurationChanged()` method?

Comment: View.invalidate() causes given View to be redrawn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't hit this situation myself, so I'm not sure (I've hit it with Activities, and the answer was to call setContentView again, then transfer over the data/state needed).  But have you tried deattaching then reattaching the fragment, so it gets to recreate its view?  Then you can re-inflate the view, which should inflate in the new mode.

If the differences are minor between the two layouts, another technique is to put both in 1 layout file and fiddle with visibilities on orientation change.